# Can not save Sarsa in Accord.NET

Tags: c#, machine-learning, accord.net, sarsa

I'm pretty new to Unity and Accord.Net but I'm currently making a small game in Unity and decided to see what I could do with some reinforcement learning to make it more interesting. Everything has been going fine except I cannot save Sarsa. I keep getting this error **"SerializationException: Type 'Accord.MachineLearning.Sarsa' in Assembly 'Accord.MachineLearning, Version=3.8.0.0, Culture=neutral is not marked as serializable."**

This issue has been mentioned before on their github : [Github/Accord.NET-SarsaNotSerializable](https://github.com/accord-net/framework/issues/1097) . It says that the issue has been fixed and even includes an example of how to get it to work properly. I've tried running it as in the example but I am still getting the same error.

I've tried using:

- Serializer.Save(sarsa, path)
- sarsa.Save(path)
- Serialzer.Save(sarsa, stream)  (from the github example above)

I'm just wondering if anyone else has experienced this issue before? I'm not too sure if maybe I am missing something or if they just never updated it to have sarsa be serializable.